# Where can I see a list of all my questions on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, activity

I want to be able to see a list of all the questions I have ever asked on the whole of the platform.  This is because there is useful material and references in the answers and comment posts.  I really need a list of my questions in one place!

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/users/6631551/user137810?tab=activity

Comment: This list includes other things but fine, thank you.

Comment: You can choose different filters to see the items you want. So pick 'posts' to see your questions and answers, and 'comments' to see only comments.

Comment: GREAT - thanks.  http://stackexchange.com/users/6631551/user137810?tab=activity
I did not see the filters.